# NSCaseInSensitive in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making a substring comparison and i did it like this

```
 if ([mystring rangeOfString:string options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
```

But this doesn't work while comparing with Read and READ

Comment: I tried this code it's working perfectly ok, please check it correctly

Comment: is tat so but i am not able to get it

Comment: please log your strings and varify manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but your code works for me... If I execute this in XCode:

```
if ([@"Read" rangeOfString:@"READ" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"NO!!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"YES!!");
}
```

I get this output:

```
YES!!
```

Comment: this is not substring comparision

Comment: but i want to make comparison with the string @"You Read" with READ so  oly i am using rangeofString

Comment: Ah sorry, I read the question too fast. I just tried your rangeOfString method in XCode and it just works. So I don't know what problem you have with it... I'll update my answer

Comment: yes it works had some prblem with the values which i was sending as sunil said i logged it nw it wrks

Answer (score 1):

It will work, try this

```
NSString *str = @"Read";
NString *matchStr = @"READ";

if ([[str lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[matchStr lowercaseString] ].location == NSNotFound) {
NSLog(@"NO!!");
} else {
NSLog(@"YES!!");
}
```